# iconv Linux Utility works inefficiently

Tags: mysql, mongodb, utf-8, etl, iconv

I use iconv utility in my ETL script to convert the csv files generated from mongo to convert the character set to utf-8 before loading them into mysql.

Occasionally the utility trims one column while converting the csv's to utf-8

```
\N|SC|XYZ|false|\N|ABC|XYZ|XXX|123|XYZ|\N|\N|123|123|NC|\N|123||||||false||\N

\N|SC|XYZ|false|\N|ABC|XYZ|XXX|123|XYZ|\N|123|123|NC|\N|123||||||false||\N
```

The command used for conversion:

```
iconv -c -f us-ascii -t UTF-8 abc-raw.csv >> abc.csv
```

As you see in the above example, an additional null column (**\N**) was trimmed after the conversion, this is not a regular behaviour, it happens only on some days. It is not environment specific as well. It happens on all the servers that particular night. If I go back and see the raw csv it does not contain any non UTF-8 characters which is supposed to be trimmed.

Can anyone please explain me is there any way to mitigate this issue, thanks in advance.

Also suggest me if there is any better tool to convert the csv to UTF-8 before loading them into mysql

Comment: Why does the title talk about efficiency? The question is about something completely different (maybe a bug in the tool).

Comment: Why use iconv at all? No need to convert ASCII, it maps to itself in UTF-8

Comment: Are you sure nothing else was chopped off those lines?